# Switch Python from miniconda to Python 2.7

Tags: python

I got access to a machine that has a miniconda Python installed in it.

```
which python
/home/moha/miniconda2/bin/python
```

I want to change it to default Python 2.7. How to do that?

I tried

```
 alias python=/usr/lib/python2.7/
```

It didn't work.

I also tried

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config python
 There is only one alternative in link group python (providing /usr/bin/python): /usr/lib/python2.7/
 Nothing to configure.
```

#### UPDATE

Output `echo $PATH`

```
echo $PATH
/usr/lib/python2.7/:/home/moha/miniconda2/bin:/home/moha/miniconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

And it didn't work as well.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `$PATH`

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha, just did.

Comment: run this to remove those path from your $PAth: `export PATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`